# Scaling the Y-Axis of a histogram

Tags: histograms

I have the following code.

```
a = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10000, 1000}];
Histogram[Total[a, {2}], PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, Automatic}]
```

I want to scale the y axis by a factor of 1000 in order to normalize. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: You need to import into *something*, i.e., `blah=Import...` and use *that* in your histogram. Also, seems like the result you're after is simply using `"Probability"` as the *hspec* in `Histogram`. Lastly, if you want to do such a simulation, no need to generate 10 million RV, just use something like `tots = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[1000, 1/2], 10000]`, get the totals directly with only 10000 rv generated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Histogram[Total[a, {2}], Automatic, #2/1000 &, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, Automatic}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the code after exporting and then importing the table into a new nb file. I edited the question. #2/1000& did not work for the imported data.

Comment: You have to name the `Import` as `coin1000`; also, what are you `Export`ing: `a` or `Total[a,{2}]`? Moreover, Import/Export of data is a different issue than plotting a histogram so in this case you should've posted a new question; don't extend the question, once it was answered, way beyond its initial scope.